# is there a way in Javascript to filter a list of products based on a user's input and remove that item without deleting it from my database?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on developing a platform for entrepreneurs, on this platform I would like new/aspiring entrepreneurs to be able to connect with other more successful entrepreneurs. I've created a feature where a user can search for other users on the platform and connect with them, but what I'm trying to do is on the "search results" page when a user clicks on the "add friend" button a friend request is sent to the selected individual on the server-side and I want the individual to be removed from the list of available individuals on display to send a friend request to.

so far I've created the feature where a user can send a friend request to anyone on the platform but I'm having trouble removing the individual that has already received a friend request from the search results list; when I click "add friend" on a selected user, my current code does remove the selected individual until I click "add friend" on another individual, then the page refreshes and the previous individual that had already received a friend request is on display once again and the most recently clicked individual is removed.

I want my code to REMEMBER all of the individuals that I've already clicked "add friend" on and filter all of them out of the search results list without deleting the actual user from my database. can anyone please help me solve this mystery? I've been going at it for a few days now and still can't figure it out no matter how much I revise my code.

Here's my current code for what I'm trying to do:

```
        const database = [//data from my users database];
        const previousInput = [];
        const userInput = req.params.id; //when I click the "add friend" button the user's id is retrieved from here.
```

I tried to write a function to get the previousInput array to remember all of the id's of the previous users I sent a friend request to, but it doesn't seem to be working because the previousInput array won't hold more than one value at any given point in time.

```
    const trackHistory = () => {
        previousInput.push(userInput);
        for (let i = 0; i < previousInput.length; i++) {
            const selectionHistory = previousInput[i];
            console.log(selectionHistory);
            return selectionHistory;
        }
    }
```

In this block of code over here I want to be able to filter the list of users coming from the users database based on the id values stored in previousInput array; but my problem is that the previousInput array refuses to store more than one value in the array even though I'm pushing new user id's into it from the userInput every time I click the "add friend" button.

```
    const filteredList = database.filter(user => {
        const userId = user._id.toString();
        const selectionHistory = trackHistory();
        if (userId !== selectionHistory) {
            return user;
        }

    });

    const users = filteredList;
    res.render("searchResults", { title: "search results", users });
```

Note: This entire project is being coded in Javascript. so please only offer solutions in Javascript, and thank you in advance for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning a list in your function, you are returning the first selectionHistory you find in the previousList. If you intend to check against all of the previousList, return the list instead and check the userid against all elements in the list.

Also, I don't completely understand your code here. Is the previousInput a global variable that all inputs get sent to? If so anytime someone receives a friend request, they would be hidden from everyone.

Instead, maybe in your database store a list of users that are invalid friend requests (already friends, have sent or recieved a request), update the database for both users every time a request is sent. Or if you really wanna go at it you can make a graph data structure to store all that data. However, the current data structure seems inadequate.

Comment: Hey Matthew, thank you for explaining that to me. to answer your question " Is the previousInput a global variable that all inputs get sent to?"  yes the "previousInput" variable is a global variable, but only the "userInput" variable pushes data into it, I'm not pushing data into it from anywhere else.

Comment: can you please exemplify what you mean by this? "You are not returning a list in your function, you are returning the first selectionHistory you find in the previousList. If you intend to check against all of the previousList, return the list instead and check the userid against all elements in the list.' because I've tried to modify my function to return the "previousInput" variable as a list and nothing has changed. I'm looking for example codes to show me how to fix this issue.

Comment: I don't want to create an additional parameter on my user model to do this, I want to approach it from the angle I've already taken where I'm keeping track of who I've already clicked on and sent a friend request to, then remove them from the search results list after clicking on them by filtering through that data list. now, you've mentioned, " a graph data structure to store all that data". can you please give me an example of this with code? because I'm not sure I know what you mean by that!

Comment: What do you think the use of the trackHistory class is? Just looking at it it looks useless as you push onto previousInputs, and then for some reason loop through previousInputs and only return one element of it, previousInputs[i]. Obviously you aren’t gonna filter for all users when your only checking for one element? In terms on the data structure you really need to think about how you are gonna structure stuff. Just making a global previousInputs array is not great practice and will lead to bugs as soon as you have multiple users saving all IDs that have been inputted to the same array.

Comment: okay, so what is the best approach to what I'm trying to do? because I don't want the platform to have any bugs later, but also to be clear, my objective was not to cycle through only one element in the loop; I thought the push method would continue to add more user ids to the previousinput array and as the user input updates the new id would also be pushed into that array since the push method is supposed to add items to the back of an array. but that's not what's happening, the array is not remembering the previous id it had before the new one got pushed into it.